# How to plot in a specific axis with DataFrame.hist(by=) in pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying plot several histogram groups in the same figure. Each group contains two conditions and I am therefore using the 'by=' argument from pandas histogram options. However, this does not work as I expected and pandas creates a new figure instead of plotting in the axis I am passing. I tried to pass four axes as well, but still no go. Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue','blue','yellow','blue','yellow'], 'area': [2,2,3,4,4]})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
df.area.hist(by=df.color, ax=ax1)
```

I'm using pandas 0.12.0, matplotlib 1.3.0 and python 2.7.5. Any suggestion that leads to a way of combining/stitching multiple 'hist(by=)-plots' in the same subplot grid is welcome.

*Update:*

Maybe this describes what I want to achieve more accurately.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue','blue','yellow','blue','yellow'], 'area': [2,2,3,4,4]})
#fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax3.plot([[2,2], [3,6]])
ax4.plot([[3,6], [2,2]])
df.area.hist(by=df.color, ax=ax1)
```

Ideally, in my example, the pandas histogram is 1,2 and should then split ax1 into two subplots. Alternatively, it could be plotted into ax1 and ax2, and then the user could make sure that the correct number of empty subplots are available.

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I see the same behaviour with pandas v 0.10.0. It seems that the variable `ax` is lost somewhere in the process of creating the histogram

Comment: pandas 0.12.0, matplotlib 1.3.0 and python 2.7.5. Added version numbers to the question as well.

Comment: if you don't us `by=` is the histogram plotted in the correct axes?

Comment: yup, then everything works fine

Comment: it smells to me like a bug. Or the behaviour with `by=` is documented. You probably best submit an issue on [pandas github page](https://github.com/pydata/pandas) and see what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of [GH7736](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7736) which was merged into pandas 0.15.0

The correct way to pass multiple plots into an existing figure is to first create all the desired axes and then pass all of them to the pandas plotting command.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue','blue','yellow','blue','yellow'], 'area': [2,2,3,4,4]})
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)
#Hide upper left corner plot and create two new subplots
ax1.axis('off')
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,4,1)
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(2,4,2)
#Plot
ax3.plot([[2,2], [3,6]])
ax4.plot([[3,6], [2,2]])
df.area.hist(by=df.color, ax=(ax,ax0)) #Pass both new subplots
```

[image]

You can carry out the subplot creation more elegantly using [GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)